# Hi, I am having trouble importing functions with webpacks

Tags: javascript, json

this is my first question but I am having issues to where my function fetchSinglePlayer() is not working inside an outside file. I have it imported/exported correctly, and getting the correct value in each of the of my console.logs. Yet when I run the puppy.data in the function, I get back 'undefined'. I can not seem to pin point exactly where its from. Any help or pointers is appreciated.

ajaxHelpers.js

```js
export const fetchSinglePlayer = async (playerId) => {
 try { 
    const response = await fetch(${APIURL}players/${playerId}); 
    const result = await response.json(); 
    console.log(result); 
    console.log(playerId); 
    if (result.error) { 
      throw result.error;
    } 
    return result.data.players;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Uh oh, trouble fetching players!', error); 
  } 
};
```

renderHelpers.js

```js
let detailButtons = [...document.getElementsByClassName("detail-button")];
for (let i = 0; i < detailButtons.length; i++) {
  const button = detailButtons[i];
  button.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    const puppyData = button.dataset.id;
    const singlePuppy = await fetchSinglePlayer(puppyData);
    console.log(puppyData);
    console.log(singlePuppy);
    return renderSinglePlayer(singlePuppy);
  });
}
```

I tried to import the fetchSinglePlayer() function in from a seperate js file into another. I get no reference errors from using the function, yet only getting undefined for the singlePuppy variable. I get the correct ID from puppyData, yet when ran through the function I get undefined.

Comment: I wanted to add that this is for a puppy bowl activity. Where I display a list of "players" that can have details to it. I generated a list with a "see details" button. I am having this issue when clicking the button for see details.

Comment: _"when I run the puppy.data"_... can't see that anywhere in your code. The argument you're passing to `fetch()` appears to be a template literal but you've forgotten the quotes. It should be `fetch(\`${APIURL}players/${playerId}\`)`

Comment: Thank you Phil. I ended up finding out about my problem. It was a issue with a return. Should have had player instead of players.